# Automatic Header Identification (Pandas / CSV)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, header

I am working on a project that parses csv files. In its current state, the user has to enter a unique string from the known column names to set the header row, both for parse column selection and to populate the columns-to-keep field.

My goal is to remove that step from the user end and automate the process, regardless of where the header row actually lies. I made a basic, hard-coded, solution to this... but I am wondering how I might go about a more Pythonic / automated way that doesn't rely on hard-coded values and logic.

Here is a minimal version of my test dataframe:

| 0 | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | this is just a placeholder to act like the first cell is filled |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 |  | this is also just a placeholder |  |  |  |  |
| 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 6 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 7 | **Text** | **Bool** | **Type** | **Active** |  |  |
| 8 | A. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.... | TRUE | t1 | yes |  |  |
| 9 | C.Nulla quis nisi vitae ante eleifend porta.D.Donec tempor felis nec lectus ultricies fringilla.... | FALSE | t5 | no |  |  |

The header row is row 7, which my basic solution identifies. But again, it is hard-coded specifically to the test dataframe.

Code below, TYIA.

```
import os, sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n=0
rownum=0
false_count=0
chklst=[]
stmt=[]
column_check = {}
row_number=0

docs = os.listdir() #set to where file is saved
os.chdir()

for file in docs:
    if file.endswith('csv'):
        if file == 'test_list1.csv':
            df = pd.read_csv('test_list1.csv', header = None)

            for row in df.iterrows():

                rownum +=1
                colnum=0

                for column in df.iloc[n]:

                    colnum += 1
                    rowindx = rownum-1
                    colindx = colnum-1
                    test=len(df.iloc[n])-1
                    
                    if df.isnull().loc[rowindx, colindx]:
                        colbool = 'False'
                        column_check[f'row {rownum} col {colnum}'] = colbool
                    else:
                        colbool = 'True'
                        column_check[f'row {rownum} col {colnum}'] = colbool
                    
                    if n < 3:
                        n += 1
                        
for key, value in column_check.items():
    false_count=0
    i=0
    chklst.append(f'{key} ')
    
    if key.endswith('col 1'):

        if value == 'False':
            col1val = 1
        elif value == 'True':
            col1val = 0

    if key.endswith('col 2'):

        if value == 'False':
            col2val = 1
        elif value == 'True':
            col2val = 0

    if key.endswith('col 3'):

        if value == 'False':
            col3val = 1
        elif value == 'True':
            col3val = 0   

    if key.endswith('col 4'):

        if value == 'False':
            col4val = 1
        elif value == 'True':
            col4val = 0

        colsum = col1val+col2val+col3val+col4val

        if colsum > 2:
            chklst.append("not header row")

        else:
            chklst.append('poss header')

        chklst.append("")

match = 'poss header'
indx_pos = chklst.index(match)
indx_pos = int((indx_pos / 5)-1) #adjusting for number of entries per row and -1 for index
found=f'The possible header is row {indx_pos}!!'
print(found)
```

This prints: **"The possible header is row 7!!"**

Comment: The approach depends on the contents of the cells above the header. what are the rules for this ?

Comment: @D.L - The program takes any uploaded zipfile and parses out any csv's it contains based on user-defined parsing criteria. It works fine with the user entering a known value to set the header text, but I'm trying to reduce the amount of steps the user has to complete beyond the actual parsing logic. In theory, the data could start on any row in the file, meaning the header won't always be at the same index.

Comment: does the header contain specific text that can be looked up ?

Comment: @D.L - with my initial dataset, yes. That is how the program already works. The program is intended for anyone to upload whatever file of csv's they want to parse. In theory, they would know their data enough to know the text in the header row. I want to __remove__ the specific text lookup part so header identification is automated on the back-end. That's what the code above does, but it is written specifically to the sample dataframe I made.

Comment: @D.L - I have two separate functions that I've made which already identify the header row based on user-defined, unique, known text from the row. Just trying to make it more user friendly by changing that to an automatic function based on number of filled columns in a row. In theory, the first complete row will be the header regardless of csv (IF there is a header row... but that part is already handled by user-selection of header / no header).

Comment: You should probably iterate over rows and compress vector of strings into a number, let's call it "confidence score". And select the most confident row as the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After toying with the code all day I think I found a solution that works. If anyone is willing to test it for me on their end, I would appreciate the feedback!

```
import os, sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

docs = os.listdir() #folder path where files are saved
os.chdir()

for file in docs:
    rownum=0
    rowindx=0
    cols=[]

    if file.endswith('csv'):
        df = pd.read_csv(file, header = None)
        
        for row in df.iterrows():
            rownum+=1
            rowindx=rownum-1
            col_count=0
            i=0

            while i < len(df.columns):

                if df.isnull().loc[rowindx, df.columns[i]]:
                    col_count=col_count
                else:
                    col_count+=1
                i+=1
           
            if col_count < len(df.columns):
                cols.append(f'row {rownum} NOPE')
            elif col_count == len(df.columns):
                cols.append(f'row matched')

        match = 'row matched'
        hdr_pos = cols.index(match)
        print(f'Header Index: {hdr_pos} \n Row: {hdr_pos+1}')
```

For each csv in the target folder, this prints:

**Header Index:** *[index #]*

   **Row:** *[index # + 1]*